# Google Custom Search API limitations and hence alternatives?

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search

I have a dataset of about 6 Million small sentences. I was trying to expand these sentences by using each sentence as a query to Google and expand each sentence from the search results.

Then I found that there is a limitation with the GCS api where you can't issue more than 100 queries/day (which is really TINY) and the paid version is so expensive.

While searching I found something call http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html#ratelimit, but they also have a limitation of 1M queries/month and given the number of queries that i want to make, this would still take 6 months which I can't afford.
Crawling Search results (even tho this violates the TOS) would not work as Google will use Captcha or even block my IP upon sensing the rate of requests the crawler would make.

I would really appreciate your input here..? Do you know any other source which will cater my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Crawl the search results and use a CAPTCHA service is the only way to feasibly do it on a budget. If you're able to use multiple IPs via a proxy then that's an advantage, as you can rate limit the crawls to avoid CAPTCHAs as much as possible.

Services I use for Google crawling:

- https://anti-captcha.com/
- http://www.scrapebox.com/

Comment: But then you would have to do all the pre processing of data, structuring, indexing and ranking of documents to a given query?

Comment: "on a budget" - i really can't spend money on this. So seems like there is no free way of doing this?

Comment: If there was a free way to do bulk Google searches, there wouldn't be a plethora of paid services to help you do it. You either pirate it with your own setup and a CAPTCHA service or you can pay someone to do it for you.